# What is ITER_IOVEC, ITER_KVEC and ITER_BVEC?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I was looking a kernel code of recent Linux kernel. In uio.h I have seen below definition

```
          ITER_IOVEC = 0,
          ITER_KVEC = 2, 
          ITER_BVEC = 4,
```

I have search its meaning online and also saw the Documentation but haven't found anything interesting.

Does anyone know what is the meaning of these constant and what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know what is the meaning of these constant and what is the difference between them?

Actually, you should look at several lines bellow in uio.h:

```
struct iov_iter {
    int type;
    size_t iov_offset;
    size_t count;
    union {
        const struct iovec *iov;
        const struct kvec *kvec;
        const struct bio_vec *bvec;
        struct pipe_inode_info *pipe;
    };
    union {
        unsigned long nr_segs;
        int idx;
    };
};
```

Theses constant allow to use different iterators for processing `a buffer of data possibly in several chunks`.

`ITER_IOVEC` used to iterate over buffers supplied by `writev/readv` functions,
`ITER_KVEC` do almost the same, but with data in kernel space, and `ITER_BVEC` to work with parts of memory mapped pages.

You can find details on [lwn](https://lwn.net/Articles/625077/), do not miss comments.